# c#: Casting variable as a generic type T

Tags: c#

I have a generic class with type T. In one of the methods i need to cast a variable as that type but I can not find out how to do it.

```
var identData = new IdentifyingData<T>((T)data);
```

I need to cast data as the type of T.

Comment: `T` is being used here, shouldn't it be a compile time constant?

Comment: How do you know that `data` is actually a `T`? You probably shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: What is the static type of `data`?

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? What error do you get?

Comment: You can add `where T : BaseClass` to your generic method, `BaseClass` being something your `data` type inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast to object previously:

```
var identData = new IdentifyingData<T>((T)(object)data);
```

Comment: This is only one of the roughly six meanings that a cast can have, and probably not the right one either.  It will compile, but if an actual conversion was needed, fail at runtime.

Comment: You should declare `data` as T or some of it inheritor or interface (see [generic type constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) for more details) to avoid type casting. Otherwise you really can get runtime errors